# Make ajax call ,success and error as functions

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, function

I want to make ajax calls and retrieve responses via functions with parameters,
but i am always getting triggered the error function and i don't know why.
Here is my code:

```js
ajaxInavdeNormal = function(url_link, successFunction, errorFunction) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url_link,
    success: function(response) {
      var respo = response;
      successFunction(respo);
    },
    error: errorFunction,
  });
};

ajaxInvadeError = function() {
  $('.div1').prepend('Internet Connection Error');
};

isItActivePopup = function(response) {
  if (response == "success") {
    $('.div1').prepend('Connection Successs');
  } else
    $('.div1').prepend('Connection Error');
};

isItActive = function(data) {
  var url_link = "http://someurl.com/somegetvar=" + data;
  ajaxInavdeNormal(url_link, isItActivePopup, ajaxInvadeError);
};

globalActions = function() {
  isItActive();
};

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    globalActions();
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look at the Network tab of your developer tools and you will be able to see what the error is. Or modify your error function to use the error object passed to it by `.ajax()`

Comment: The error function takes three arguments. Look at them to find out what the error is. Also look at the Console in your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @Turnip & Quentin thanks guys , found the error . As it seems above , i was trying to pass the data via get method , in here **"isItActive = function(data)"** exactly but i didn't include it when calling it at  **"globalActions = function() { isItActive();};"** and of course there were no data to process .

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote above, I was trying to pass the data via get method:

```
isItActive = function(data)
```

However, I didn't include it when calling it at

```
globalActions = function() { isItActive();};
```

As a result, there was no data to process.